# Call/load Jquery Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a login screen which the user logs in using Jquery and AJAX. That's fine. Now what I want is that if the user logs in correctly, I want to load another page.

I tried using  document.location = "home.html"; but that refreshes my page. What I want is like that transition that normally we have when we click on  tag like

```
<a href="SchoolMaterials.html"> <!-- this does not refresh -->
```

I don't know if I explained myself clearly.

Thanks

Comment: But shouldn't you redirect on the same page and show the user that he/she is logged in?

Comment: yes but I want the same transition as if the user clicked on an <a> tag

Comment: What is the difference in transition you see? A click on a link that has not been changed into some responsive ajaxing will load a new page in the browser. Something I would expect would be a location change in the success handler of the ajax

Comment: The difference I see is that if I see the inspect element, when the user logs in, it changes to home.html and when the user clicks on a link found in home.html the inspect element is still home.html

Comment: So you have some kind of framework, jquery mobile or other that keeps the page url and loads other content into a div. If you find that framework, just do the same in your success

Comment: Yes I am using jquery. I didn't understand what you meant

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to load the page in your callback function of successful login with:

```
$("#the_div_container_for_new_page").load("SchoolMaterials.html")
```

UPDATED:

it is something like this:

```
$(document).ready() {
    function login() {
        //post with ajax to login
        $.post(......, function(result){
            if (result.success) {
                // load some page after successful login.
                $('#id_of_container_div').load("thepage.html");
                return;
            } else {
                // handle error
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do this, data-url is changed to the id use (for example id_of_container_div)

Comment: ah! you are using jquery-mobile. You should use changePage() of JQM. http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/

Answer (score 0):

window.location is just what you need. You can also create an anchor element using jQuery and simulate a click on it :

```
$("<a href='your url'></a>").click();
```

But i wouldn't recommend that, it's better to post your data to the server and redirect to the page you want.

Comment: What do you mean by post data to my server.. I got all data needed when user logged in

Comment: Avoid using ajax for login in, submit the form. Are you using any MV* frameworks ?